# Working With multiple instance of a windows form in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have three forms (form1, form2, form3) in a windows application using vb.net

form1 has a button (button1). Onclick of button1, I want to open form2 in such a way that it can also open multiple times. I achieved this with the code below:

```
Dim myForm As New Form2
myForm.Show()
```

Now form2 has a button (button2), and a label (label1). Onclick of button2, I want to open a single instance of form3 a dialog, so I have the code below:

```
form3.showdialog()
```

form3 has a textbox (textbox1).

My problem is that I want when I fill textbox1, I want the value to appear in label1 of form2 that opened the form3, I tried the code below, but it did not work:

```
form2.label1.Text = textbox1.Text
```

I need to update form2 (the last active one) once form3 has been closed
Can anybody help me out please?

Comment: Do you need to have `Form2` display the changes, as they are made, while `Form3` is still visible, or do you just need to update `Form2` once `Form3` has been closed?

Comment: So you plan to have multiple instances of `Form2`, all opening the same instance of `Form3`? Screenshot could help explain your need.

Comment: @StevenDoggart :  I need to update form2 once form3 has been closed.

Answer (score 1):

When you go to show the `Form3` as a dialog, you should be able to do:

```
Dim f3 As New Form3
f3.ShowDialog()
Me.label1.Text = f3.textbox1.Text 'Copy the value out of the dialog
```

Comment: I want change the value label1 when I click on a button on form3, so i want the code to be in form3. can u help me with that?

Comment: @Toni You'd have to pass the label or the form2 instance to Form3 in it's constructor, so you have access to it.  This will change the label when you close the form (which is more common).